# Array Slicing with step 2

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Have array like

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].
```

How I can get array like this:

```
[1,2,5,6,9,10]
```

**take 2 elements with step 2(::2)**

I try something like `arr[:2::2]`.it's not work

Comment: link doesnot help

Answer (score 2):

`[:2::2]` is not valid Python syntax.  A slice only takes 3 values - start, stop, step.  You are trying to provide 4.

Here's what you need to do:

```
In [233]: arr = np.arange(1,11)                                                               
In [234]: arr                                                                                 
Out[234]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

first reshape to form groups of 2:

```
In [235]: arr.reshape(5,2)                                                                    
Out[235]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

now slice to get every other group:

```
In [236]: arr.reshape(5,2)[::2 ,:]                                                             
Out[236]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

and then back to 1d:

```
In [237]: arr.reshape(5,2)[::2,:].ravel()                                                     
Out[237]: array([ 1,  2,  5,  6,  9, 10])
```

You have to step back a bit, and imagine the array as a whole, and ask how to make it fit the desire pattern.